# unable to generate Hyperledger network artifacts

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm following [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/stable/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) link to setup multi organizations for business network

I have cloned the git code and tried to setup my first network by following the instructions [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/build_network.html)

I have followed each and every step till I reach command to generate using `./byfn.sh -m generate` it exists saying cryptogen tool not found which can be seen below.

```
text@blockchain-2:~/fabric-tools/fabric-samples/first-network$ ./byfn.sh -m generate
Generating certs and genesis block for with channel 'mychannel' and CLI timeout of '10000' seconds and CLI delay of '3' second
s
Continue (y/n)? y
proceeding ...
cryptogen tool not found. exiting
```

How to fix this issue and proceed further?

Comment: I never tried the composer tutorial but what I'd do is use the find command to locate cryptogen, and then adjust your PATH accordingly;.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have Docker and Docker Compose installed, you will also need to install some platform specific binaries (including cryptogen).  If you have already installed these binaries then adding the folder containing the binaries to PATH will help.

These 2 documents below in the Hyperledger Fabric will help with the pre-requisites, but don't run the byfn.sh script - run that script from the clone of the sstone repo, and run it with the parameters specified in the [Multi-Org Composer Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html)

There are the 2 fabric pre-req docs:
[Cryptogen and other binaries](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/samples.html#binaries) and 
[Fabric Pre-reqs](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/prereqs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `/bin` and `/first-network` are in the same directory because `cryptogen` belongs to `/bin`

```
$ /learn/hyperledger/fabric-samples$ ls
balance-transfer  chaincode-docker-devmode  first-network    README.md
basic-network     config                    high-throughput  scripts
bin               fabcar                    LICENSE
chaincode         fabric-ca                 MAINTAINERS.md
```